# Using few proxy servers to explore html pages in C# application

Tags: c#, proxy, using

Im making simple application which collects information about automotive advertusements.

How can I add several proxy servers so that the application uses alternately different addresses, so that the portal from which I download data does not block me from visiting and downloading data from the website?

My code, maybe you will need it:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var url = "https://www.otomoto.pl/osobowe/audi/a3/?page=" + i;

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

            var Cars = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                .Equals("offers list")).ToList();

            var CarsListItems = Cars[0].Descendants("article")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("data-test", "")
                .Contains("search-result-item")).ToList();

            foreach (var CarsParamsList in CarsListItems)
            {
                var marka = CarsParamsList.Descendants("a")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                    .Equals("offer-title__link")).First().InnerText.Trim('\n', ' ');
                Console.WriteLine(marka);


                var year = CarsParamsList.Descendants("li")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("data-code", "")
                    .Equals("year")).First().InnerText.Trim('\n', ' ');
                Console.WriteLine(year);

                var mileage = CarsParamsList.Descendants("li")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("data-code", "")
                    .Equals("mileage")).First().InnerText.Trim('\n', ' ');
                Console.WriteLine(mileage);

                try
                {
                    var engine = CarsParamsList.Descendants("li")
                      .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("data-code", "")
                      .Equals("engine_capacity")).First().InnerText.Trim('\n', ' ');
                    Console.WriteLine(engine);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Brak informacji");
                }

                var fuel = CarsParamsList.Descendants("li")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("data-code", "")
                    .Contains("fuel_type")).First().InnerText.Trim('\n', ' ');
                Console.WriteLine(fuel);
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution:

```
private static async void GetHtmlAsync()
    {
        string[] SPlist = new string[10] {
         "94.75.76.10:8080",
         "142.44.243.144:8080",
         "178.32.80.234:1080",
         "183.88.244.87:8080",
         "5.128.35.36:3128",
         "139.59.53.106:3128",
         "54.37.17.150:8080",
         "109.193.195.11:8080",
         "35.199.105.78:8080",
         "95.208.208.237:8080" 
     };

        int actualServerProxy;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var url = "https://www.otomoto.pl/osobowe/audi/a3/?page=" + i + 1;

            actualServerProxy = ((int)((i + 1) / 50)) % SPlist.Length;

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy("http://" + SPlist[actualServerProxy]),
                UseProxy = true,
            };

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
```